# swift 3 - localization for push notification not work

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, localizable.strings

Im trying to localize push notifications (swift 3, ios 10) with the payload:

```
{ 
"aps":{
        "alert":{  
           "title_loc_key":"NOTIFICATION_NEW_FRIEND_REQUEST_TITLE",
           "title-loc-args":[],
           "loc_key":"NOTIFICATION_NEW_FRIEND_REQUEST_BODY",
           "loc-args":[]
        },
       "mutable_content":1,
       "category":"new_friend_request",
       "badge":0,
       "sound":"default"
    }
}
```

on the Localizable.strings i have:

```
"NOTIFICATION_NEW_FRIEND_REQUEST_TITLE" = "some text";
"NOTIFICATION_NEW_FRIEND_REQUEST_BODY" = "some text"
```

My system language is en
The problem is that notification come (my Iphone is vibrating) but nothing is showing. Whats the problem and how to fix that?

Comment: `title_loc_key` vs `title-loc-key` and `loc_key` vs `loc-key` The doc seems to define the keys with "-" and you are mixing (using "-" and "_") https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html

Comment: thx, I know, stupid mistake ((

Comment: Don't forget to vote the correct answer @TabirtaAdrian

Comment: @OlegDanu - piece of developer :D, "Don't forget to vote the correct answer" - Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`title_loc_key` vs `title-loc-key` and `loc_key` vs `loc-key`.

The [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html) defines the keyword separators with `-` and you are mixing (using `-` for `...arg` and `_` for `...key`)

> **Storing Localized Content in Your App Bundle**
>
> If you use a consistent set of messages for your notifications, you
>   can store localized versions of the message text in your app bundle
>   and use the `loc-key` and `loc-args` keys in your payload to specify which
>   message to display. The `loc-key` and `loc-args` keys define the message
>   content of the notification. When present, the local system searches
>   the app’s `Localizable.strings` files for a key string matching the
>   value in `loc-key`. It then uses the corresponding value from the
>   strings file as the basis for the message text, replacing any
>   placeholder values with the strings specified by the `loc-args` key.
>   (You can also specify a title string for the notification using the
>   `title-loc-key` and `title-loc-args` keys.)

Comment: Do you have any idea about this issue?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50347766/error-firebase-cloud-functions-typescript-payload-contains-an-invalid-value-for