# Error Firebase Cloud Functions Typescript Payload contains an invalid value for the "notification.loc-args" property

Tags: typescript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

Receiving following error message from Firebase Cloud functions log for my Firebase Function. I am trying to create a remote push notification payload with localization which has dynamic values.

> Error: Messaging payload contains an invalid value for the "notification.loc-args" property. Values must be strings.

TypeScript code for payload

```
  var values : String[] = [];
  values.push('Johnny Appleseed');
  const payload = {
    notification: {
      'title-loc-key': 'INVITE_PUSH_TITLE',  
      'loc-key': 'INVITE_PUSH_BODY',
      'loc-args': values,
      'type': 'Invite',
      'fromName': name,
      'userId': uid,
    }
  };
```

'loc-args' property already contains string array. What is wrong here?

> Following sample shows how it suppose to be, based on [Apple
>   documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html)

Localization Parameter for iOS

```
"GAME_PLAY_REQUEST_FORMAT" = "%@ and %@ have invited you to play Monopoly";
```

Payload

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "loc-key" : "GAME_PLAY_REQUEST_FORMAT",
            "loc-args" : [ "Jenna", "Frank"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is telling you the values must be strings.  They can't be arrays of strings.  This limitation is enforced by FCM, not Apple.  You have to observe FCM rules when using FCM to send a message.

Answer (score 3):

Following payload for FCM solved my problem.

```
const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: 'You have a new team request!',
      body: `${name} sent team request.!`,
      'title_loc_key': 'TEAM_INVITE_PUSH_TITLE',  
      'body_loc_key': 'TEAM_INVITE_PUSH_BODY',
      'body_loc_args': `["${name}"]`
    },
    data: {
      type: 'teamInvite',
      fromName: name,
      userId: uid
    }
  };
```